# Concatenating objects in a For loop

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, concatenation

I am wanting to perform the concatenation as shown below in the objConcat variable but for X number of objects. Sometimes I'll need to concatenate two objects, and sometimes I'll need to concatenate 50 objects.

How can I iterate this in a For loop where I don't have to manually create these individual object variables?

The importData() function returns an object.

```
var obj1 = importData(0);
var obj2 = importData(1);
var obj3 = importData(2);
var objConcat = obj1.concat(obj2).concat(obj3);
```

Comment: By Object do you mean Array? If not, can you elaborate on what you mean by concatenate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the first data and save it in a variable. Then, loop through the rest and concatenate each of it to the initial variable.

```
var objConcat = importData(0);
var n = 50;
for (var i=1; i<n; i++) {
    objConcat = objConcat.concat(importData(i));
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of an object method Object.concat.  And in trying it in GAS I get an error `Cannot find function concat in object [object Object]`.

Comment: This worked perfectly and captures the logic I was thinking of but couldn’t figure out. Thank you so much!